# (Self-Study) UMVUE of the mean of a normal distribution

Tags: statistics, order-statistics, sufficient-statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from normal(θ,1). Is there an UMVUE of $θ^2$ here?

$X^2-1$ is an unbiased estimator of $θ^2$. First thing that came to my mind is to use Lehmann-Scheffe Theorem. But the problem is that, according to my calculations, n(θ,1) doesn't have a complete statistic since, even though $\overline{X}=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{n}X_i}{n}$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for θ (easy to show), it is not complete (again easy to show). Thus there is simply no complete statistic for n(θ,1). Another way to prove it may use the condition that an UMVUE must be uncorrelated with all unbiased estimators of 0 (and vice-versa). But I don't have a candidate for UMVUE at all.

Can anybody give a clue about this question? Thanks!

Comment: $\overline X$ *is* a complete sufficient statistic for this family. And $T=\overline X^2-\frac{1}{n}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta^2$. By Lehmann-Scheffe, $T$ is the UMVUE of $\theta^2$.

Comment: It would help if you show your work that led you to conclude that there is no complete statistic here.

Comment: yes, after your comment I figured out that I should have used the Laplace transformation to show that the mean is a complete statistic. You are completely right, thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a one-parameter exponential family. That $\overline X$ is complete and sufficient follows directly from the structure of the joint density of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.

Comment: Do you mean [this theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322381/what-is-exponential-family-criterion-to-test-the-sufficiency-and-completeness-of)?

Comment: In n(θ,1) the parameter space contains all the points (θ), which makes it the whole real line, right? So it is an open set, and the theorem you just referred follows?

Comment: Yes, the parameter space is the real line $\mathbb R$ itself.

Comment: great! I've actually seen this theorem before but had some doubts about the concept of parameter space. thanks again.